# DQN layers when state space and action space are multi dimensional

Tags: deep-learning, python, keras, deep-rl, deep-neural-networks

I have built my own RL environment, where a state is composed of two elements: the agent's position and a matrix of 0s and 1s (1 if a user has requested a service from the agent, 0 otherwise); an action is composed of 3 elements: the movement the agent chooses (up, down, left or right), a matrix of 0s and 1s (1 if a resource has been allocated to a user, 0 otherwise), and a vector representing the allocation of another type of resource (the vector contains the values allocated to the users).

I am currently trying to build a Deep Q Learning agent, I am a bit confused however as to what model (example Sequential), what type of layers (example Dense layers), how many layers, what activation mode I should use, and what the state and action sizes are. (Taking this code as a reference [cartpole dqn agent](https://github.com/the-deep-learners/TensorFlow-LiveLessons/blob/master/notebooks/cartpole_dqn.ipynb))

I also do not know what my inputs and outputs should be.

The examples I have come across are rather simple and I don't know how to approach setting it all up for my agent.

Comment: assuming your agents position is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, you could have a network that takes as input the position and passes it through a fully connected layer, the matrix passed through a convolutional layer, and the concatenate the two outputs of those layers to pass through further fully connected layers.

Comment: Genius ! Thank you so much for your answer ^^

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer since you seem happy with it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily the only way to do this but it would be the approach I'd take.

Assuming your agents position is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then I would have the network take as input this position vector and pass it through a fully connected layer. I would also take as input the matrix and pass it through a convolutional layer(s) and flatten the output so it is now also a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d'}$. I would then concatenate these together so you have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d + d'}$ and pass this through some fully connected layers as usual.

As for *how many* layers and which activation to use this is something you'll have to do by trial and error as this really is problem specific.

Your output would typically be a score for each of the action combinations, though as one of your outputs is a matrix this could potentially make things expensive to compute as you would need $2^{n \times m}$ binary representations just for the matrix ($n$ is the number of rows and $m$ is the number of columns).